# How to use s-nail with unattended-upgrades?

Tags: mailx, unattended-upgrades

My ISP blocks port 25 and I want to send email after `unattended-upgrades` completes. I set things up so that I can successfully send mail with `s-nail`, but `unattended-upgrades` still isn't sending me email and I don't know why.

## s-nail setup

First, the `s-nail` configuration.

#### Installing s-nail

I came across info for `heirloom-mailx`, but delving into it, the maintainers said, "ahh, you don't need that, just create a link from /usr/bin/mail to s-nail!" So that is what I did:

```bsh
# first, uninstall any mailx programs you have
sudo apt remove bsd-mailx
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/mail  # just in case something is still installed

# install s-nail and link it
sudo apt install s-nail
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/s-nail /usr/bin/mail
```

#### $HOME/.mailrc

```rc
v15-compat

from="CronUpdates <cron@mydomain.com>"
sendwait
sendcharsets=utf-8,iso-8859-1

mta=smtp://cron%40mydomain.com:<redacted>@smtppro.zoho.com:587 \
smtp-auth=login \
smtp-use-starttls
```

which is of course `chmod 600 $HOME/.mailrc`'d as it is supposed to be.

#### $HOME/send_test_email.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

EMAIL_SUBJECT="Cron Email"
TO_ADDRESS="admin@mydomain.com"

echo 'Hello world!' | s-nail -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" "$TO_ADDRESS"
```

which is of course `chmod u+x $HOME/send_test_email.sh`'d, allowing us to:

```bsh
./send_test_email.sh
# success!
```

Woo-hoo, I get an email!

## unattended-upgrades setup

Next, the unattended-upgrades configuration in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. This represents an ubuntu configuration, but I have a raspberry pi configuration that is a little different, but has the same issue.

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
  "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-app-security";
  "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
};

Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
};

Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "auto";

Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "admin@mydomain.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport "always";
```

I can `--dry-run` unattended upgrades, *if there's anything to upgrade*, but I don't think that sends an email. Still, that's useful:

```bsh
# do a dry-run to iron out any issues that you can with unattended-upgrades
sudo unattended-upgrades -v -d --dry-run

# doesn't send an email, but that's operating as designed :(
```

Then, *if there's anything to upgrade* (which makes everything very difficult to debug, especially since `apt-cache madison` only returns one result), I can drop `--dry-run` and it will allegedly attempt to send the email:

```
machine$ sudo unattended-upgrades -v -d
Running on the development release
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=impish, o=Ubuntu,a=impish-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=impish-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=impish-infra-security, o=Ubuntu,a=impish-updates
Initial blacklist:
Initial whitelist (not strict):
Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/download.docker.com_linux_ubuntu_dists_impish_stable_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=impish,c=stable,v=,o=Docker,l=Docker CE arch='amd64' site='download.docker.com' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=28335 ID:44> with -32768 pin

... many lines later ...

Package docker-ce-rootless-extras has a higher version available, checking if it is from an allowed origin and is not pinned down.
Extracting content from /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log since 2022-04-15 17:53:56
Sending mail to admin@mydomain.com
mail returned: 0
```

Oh no, I don't get any email!

The above configuration represents many hours of research, trial, and error attempting to get both email and unattended-upgrades to work; both of which work, but now must work together...

How can I make unattended-upgrades actually send its email given that I must use the `.mailrc` configuration defined above?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the same problem and found a workaround.

We can look into the [source code](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/5f979a25fda0f399a6c426e9972ed4c2a0e15cf0/unattended-upgrade) of the `unattended-upgrades` script. 
As you can see, it supports only `mail` or `sendmail` commands.

```
MAIL_BINARY = "/usr/bin/mail"
SENDMAIL_BINARY = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
```

The following lines send mail using the `mail` command,
which has a similar interface as `s-nail`
(`-r` for *f**r**om address*, `-s` for ***s**ubject*):

```
mail = subprocess.Popen(
    [MAIL_BINARY, "-r", from_address, "-s", subject, to_address],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=False)
```

You can make a symbolic link from `/usr/bin/mail` to `/usr/bin/s-nail`.

- make sure that `/usr/sbin/sendmail` is not installed
  as it first tries to use `sendmail`
- `s-nail` is configured for the root user (config file: `/etc/s-nail.rc`)
  because `unattended-upgrades` runs as the root user